# Flutter web - Webview Iframe

Tags: flutter, iframe, flutter-layout, flutter-web

For playing videos in Flutter I am trying to use a flutter-video player, Which works fine in android and Ios, But when porting it to the Web, how to provide compatibility.
Should I be using Html5 web player inside webview in flutter, So it works as a widget in Web, also
Does using a webview as a widget in android, Does it directly translate to an Iframe in Flutter Web

Comment: Check this [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package from the flutter team. This should work in web as well.

Comment: @AbhilashChandran thanks, the answer makes sense, But I also wanted to know if using a webview in native will directly translate to an Iframe in Flutter web.